# Drawing multiple polygons in canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, shapes

I have a canvas, myCanvas where i want to draw multiple polygons on the location where i specify the points.

```
PointCollection polygonpoints = new PointCollection();

private void myCanvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //add polygon collection  
    Point p = e.GetPosition(MapGrid);
    polygonpoints.Add(p);
}

private void myCanvas_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Polygon poly = new Polygon();
    poly.Points = polygonpoints;
    poly.Fill = Brushes.AliceBlue;
    MapCanvas.Children.Add(poly); 
    polygonpoints.Clear(); // this is making clear the polygon but the pointcollection is remain 
}
```

polygonpoints.Clear - i planned to use this for clearing the polygon points for next polygon. but this is not happening.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: What is not happening exactly?

Comment: The next step would certainly be to show the current Polygon while you're left-clicking. You would first create a new Polygon and add it to the Canvas. Keep a reference to the current Polygon as class member (instead of a PointCollection). Add a Point to its Points property on every left click. On right click, create and add a new Polygon and operate on that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is you're passing `polygonpoints` rather than a copy of it as `poly.Points`.

Change the polygon creation to

```
Polygon poly = new Polygon
{
    Points = new PointCollection(polygonpoints),
    Fill = Brushes.AliceBlue
};
```

Comment: Note that `PointCollection` also is a `ICollection<Point>`, so there's no need to change that declaration (unless you explain any possible advantages).

Comment: Thats it .. Thank you!